# Drawing a Static Line Using Arduino, Gameduino 1.0 (VGA) and GLCD/TFT Display

Tags: arduino, line, vga

I am super new at this, so please be patient with me. I am attempting to design a user interface on a VGA display using an Arduino UNO and a Gamduino 1.0, and need help with drawing two axes (x and y). Essentially, I need to draw two static lines on a monitor where the x-axis pans from left to right on the display, and the y-axis is 1/8 from the left of the display, panning 1/2 from the top of the display until the bottom.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If it's static you'll want it as a background (as opposed to sprite).

There's a tutorial here on setting backgrounds:
http://excamera.com/sphinx/gameduino/tutorials/frogger1.html

I'm in the process of something similar so I'll post up my code soon (gameduino just arrived in the mail today).